# How do I configure my duct dampers for summer and winter?

Tags: hvac

My levers on my duct work for my furnace are not marked with a "WINTER", "SUMMER" How do I know which way it opened and closed?

Comment: What make and model are we talking about? Would you post a picture of the furnace, including the lever?

Comment: Ducts are not normally reconfigured for winter and summer. What makes you think they should be?

Comment: @isherwood I had never seen dampers until I moved into a 3-story townhouse in VA. They definitely help to keep the 3 floors reasonably comfortable in the different seasons.

Comment: Sure, but I've always done it on a room-by-room basis for more granular control.

Answer (score 1):

Dampers are used to control which areas get more airflow. In the summer, you want more (cold) air going to the upper stories and less to the lower stories. This is due to the fact that warm air rises, and so the upper stories will naturally be warmer than the lower. In the winter, this is reversed, so you want more (warm) air going to the lower stories and less going to the upper.

How much to open or close the dampers is probably going to be a personal preference as well as depend on the layout of the house and ductwork, so you may need to experiment a bit.

Comment: This can also be room specific. Many people like a cool bedroom for sleeping so they change the damper on the bedroom duct from open all the way in the a/c cooling season to much more closed in the furnace heating season.

Comment: @JimStewart Indeed, although those levers are typically located on the registers (at least in my experience). Dampers, at least in the sense the OP is talking about, typically are located right next to the furnace and control airflow to one or more of the main trunk lines, allowing you to adjust airflow to an entire story or two.

Comment: Once you have figured out the optimal damper settings, mark the positions of the levers: SUMMER/WINTER or HEAT/COOL for posterity.